# Are there any lite text editors in console mode on Windows?

Tags: vim, text-editors

I know a few:

Renowned text editor:

- [MS-DOS Editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS_Editor)
  [image]
- [Vim/Vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor))[image]

But, MS-DOS Editor is a 16-bit software which cannot be run in Win7 (64-bit), and Vim/Vi is not lite.

Are there any **lite** text editors in console mode on Windows ?

Required limitation:

- RAM: less than 8MB.

Comment: I generally think of VI as a fairly lightweight text editor, compared to Emacs or something like Eclipse.  So my question is, what defines a lightweight text editor for you?  Startup time, EXE size, etc?

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic, and to suitably answer your question, you'd have to properly define **lite**: For example single executable, low memory / CPU requirements of XXX MB / MIPS, or portable install?!

Comment: @Ingo Karkat Oh sorry, my mistake. Memory: 8MB, and portable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you prune most of the *runtime files* (like colorschemes, syntax definitions, etc.), and compile it with the `--with-features=tiny` flag, you will get a **small Vim** installation. Many Linux distributions (like *Ubuntu*) ship with such a `vim-tiny` package; to get the full-featured Vim (and graphical GVIM), you need to install additional packages.

There's even such a Vim distribution for Android smartphones ([vim touch vim editor on android](http://www.cnx-software.com/2012/04/03/vim-touch-vim-editor-on-android/), also with an optional full runtime), proving that Vim can be quite lightweight.